# C# JSON Deserialize Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: json, c#-4.0, serialization, deserialization

JSON Data:

```
{
  "MetaData ": {
    "Id": "1",
    "CreatedBy": "Ravi",
    "CreatedOn": "06/01/2018",
    "State": "Completed",
    "Level": "Curator"
  },
  "tbDm": {
    "textBox1": "Ravi",
    "textBox2": "Chaitag",
    "textBox3": "Jp",
    "textBox4": "Ch"
  },
  "tbCO": {
    "textBox5": "Cha",
    "textBox7": "C",
    "textBox8": "ra",
    "textBox6": "j"
  }
}
```

This is My Code:

```
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Save = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox1, tbDm);
    }

    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox2, tbDm);
    }

    private void textBox3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox3, tbDm);
    }

    private void textBox4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox4, tbDm);
    }

    private void textBox5_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox5, tbDm);
    }

    private void textBox6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox6, tbDm);
    }

    private void textBox7_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox7, tbDm);
    }
   private void textBox8_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Savedata(Save, textBox8, tbDm);
    }

    public void Savedfile(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> save)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(save, new KeyValuePairConverter());
        string FilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Send");
        if (!Directory.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath);
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FilePath + "\\" + "output.json", json);
    }
    private void Savedata(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> currentDict, TextBox textbox, TabPage tab)
    {

        var thisdata = currentDict.ContainsKey(tab.Text) ? currentDict[tab.Text] : new Dictionary<string, string>();
        thisdata[textbox.Name] = textbox.Text;
        currentDict[tab.Name] =thisdata;
        Savedfile(currentDict);
    }

    public class MetaData
    {
        public string MetaDataList { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Createdby { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }

    }


    public class Offlinedta
    {
        public MetaData metadata { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> currentDict { get; set; }

        public Offlinedta()
        {
            MetaData obj = new MetaData();
            obj.Id = "1";
            obj.Createdby= "Ravi";
            obj.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            obj.State = "Completed";
            obj.Level = "Curator";
        }
    }
```

I just want above json Format..Please help me.

till now its working below json..

"tbDm": {
        "textBox1": "Ravi",
        "textBox2": "Chaitag",
        "textBox3": "Jp",
        "textBox4": "Ch"
      },
      "tbCO": {
        "textBox5": "Cha",
        "textBox7": "C",
        "textBox8": "ra",
        "textBox6": "j"
      }

How to append Metadata  information to current json..